# In a Maven project, how can I automatically update the version all child modules, plus the parent?

Tags: maven-2, maven-release-plugin, multi-module

I have a multi-module project.

```
parent POM (1.0-SNAPSHOT)
|-- module1 (1.0-SNAPSHOT)
|-- module2 (1.0-SNAPSHOT)
`-- module3 (1.0-SNAPSHOT)
```

When I execute mvn release:prepare it verify that parent POM has a SNAPSHOT version and all dependent modules don't have a SNAPSHOT version. How automatically update all child modules from SNAPSHOT to the next release version?

I would like automatically increment version for all modules.

Comment: Using a "fixed" parent version as [defined here](http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/MNG-624?focusedCommentId=242865&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3Acomment-tabpanel#action_242865) might also help you.

Comment: here is the link to the relevant comment in the linked discussion : http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/MNG-624?focusedCommentId=242865&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:comment-tabpanel#comment-242865

Answer (score 31, accepted):

The release plugin can handle that. Did you check [Updating POM Versions](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-release-plugin/examples/update-versions.html)? But...
I don't get something. *Changing the version in the POMs from x-SNAPSHOT to a new version* and *bumping the version in the POMs to a new value y-SNAPSHOT* should be done by `release:prepare` as explained in [Prepare a Release](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-release-plugin/examples/prepare-release.html). What is going wrong when using this goal?

**Update:** The [`autoVersionSubmodules`](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-release-plugin/prepare-mojo.html#autoVersionSubmodules) parameter might be what you're looking for. From the  [Prepare a Release](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-release-plugin/examples/prepare-release.html) example:

> #### Multi-module projects
>
> You will be prompted for the version
>   number for each module of the project.
>   If you prefer that every module gets
>   the same version as the parent POM,
>   you can set the option
>   `autoVersionSubmodules` to `true`. Now you
>   will be asked only once for the
>   release version and the next
>   development version.

#### Snippet of parent pom.xml

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-release-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>x.y.z</version>
            <configuration>
                <goals>deploy</goals>
                <autoversionsubmodules>true</autoversionsubmodules>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Comment: For example command mvn versions:set -DnewVersion=1.0 update the parent POM and modules versions. But I don't want to update the parent version...

What is the best practices for releasing the multi-module projects?

Comment: release:prepare require that all modules have a non-SNAPSHOT version
Therefore I should manually change versions for all modules. For instance the project consist of 15th modules. Therefore I finding a way how to update automatically all modules.

Comment: @eugenn No, you don't have to change that manually, the `release:prepare` goal does it for you (check the link again).

Comment: Thank you Pascal, you are right! release:prepare works well. Possible I have some configurations issues with my parent POM.

Comment: A new maven plugin comes to adress this problem: http://mojo.codehaus.org/flatten-maven-plugin/examples/example-multiple-versions.html

Comment: @eugenn But if you l leave the version of parent unchanged this will cause problems. I did myself. When you release a new version you will want to update dependencies that are on parent and you will screw up all projects but last version. Be careful!

Answer (score 38):

A flexible way to set poms versions, multi-modules projects included, is [Versions Maven Plugin](http://www.mojohaus.org/versions-maven-plugin/).

```
mvn versions:set -DnewVersion=your_new_version
```

It will adjust all pom versions, parent versions and children versions in a multi-module project.

then

```
mvn versions:commit
```

or

```
mvn versions:revert
```

Comment: `commit` and `revert` act on the back-up pom files created during `set`, which is IMO unnecessary since I'm using version control and could simply revert to what's in git. By adding `-DgenerateBackupPoms=false` to the `set` command, there is no need for either `commit` or `set` afterwards. My 2 cents.

Comment: It's a kind of a dry run that lets user check the results before doing it effectively. But yeah, you can go straight forward also. But in case of a mistake, it might be less funny to revert a git commit than that set-commit IMHO.

Comment: oh it's definitely handy in some situations, but the naming misled me for a while and I had to look up in the docs exactly what it did, just to be sure. I think I would have called the command `versions:deleteBackupPoms` and `versions:revertToBackupPoms`.

Answer (score 7):

1. Make the version of all sub-project be defined in its parent pom.xml.
2. Make sure all sub-projects versions are the same to their parent's version.

   ```
   <groupId>com.xyz</groupId>
   <artifactId>module-1</artifactId>
   <packaging>jar</packaging>

   <parent>
     <groupId>com.xyz</groupId>
     <artifactId>xyz-parent</artifactId>
     <version>1.0.123-SNAPSHOT</version>
   </parent>
   ```

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
   <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">

     <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
     <artifactId>xyz-parent</artifactId>
     <groupId>com.xyz</groupId>
     <version>1.0.123-SNAPSHOT</version>
     <packaging>pom</packaging>
     <name>xyz-parent</name>

     <dependencyManagement>
       <dependencies>

       <!-- Message -->
       <dependency>
         <groupId>com.xyz</groupId>
         <artifactId>module-1</artifactId>
         <version>${project.version}</version>
       </dependency>

       <dependency>
         <groupId>com.xyz</groupId>
         <artifactId>module-2</artifactId>
         <version>${project.version}</version>
       </dependency>

     </dependencyManagement>
   </project>
   ```
3. Create another pom.xml to group those project together.

   ```
   <modules>   
     <module>../xyz-parent</module>
     <module>../module-1</module>
     <module>../module-2</module>      
   </modules>
   ```
4. Then update the parent project's version and then build it by below command.

   ```
   mvn versions:set -DnewVersion=1.0.1004-SNAPSHOT
   mvn clean install
   ```
5. Then update the parent's version which is defined in those sub-project to the latset one

   ```
   mvn -N versions:update-child-modules
   ```
6. Then build them together.

   ```
   @echo on
   cd   .\xyz-parent
   call mvn versions:set -DnewVersion=1.0.1004-SNAPSHOT -o
   call mvn versions:commit -o
   call mvn clean install -o
   :::http://www.mojohaus.org/versions-maven-plugin/examples/update-child-modules.html
   cd ..\xyz-buildaggregate-ide
   call mvn -N versions:update-child-modules -o
   call mvn clean install -o
   ```

Comment: @DoctorWho Yes, I've tested it on 3.6.0 and it works. It's still versions-maven-plugin and more information including versions info may be found here http://www.mojohaus.org/versions-maven-plugin/usage.html

Answer (score 3):

There is a potentially better option over at https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MNG-624?focusedCommentId=14415968&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:comment-tabpanel#comment-14415968

That is a workaround for the fact that you can't refer to the top level pom in the sub-module poms without having an explicit version listed.  (which is what bug MNG-624 is about)
It explains how you can have a single location for the version (in a top-level profiles.xml file), and simply have a property references in all the pom.xml files (i.e. ${currentVersion})

However, in this scheme release:prepare probably won't update profiles.xml for you.